# How to findout Device Name/build Using UserAgentUtils-1.2.3 Java Api?

Tags: java, mobile

I can find out OS Name,OS Manufacturer,DEVICE TYPE,Browser Type,Browser Name,Browser Version using UserAgentUtils api
how can i findout Device Name/build ?

example :HTC Sensation Build/IML74K and LG .....

```
String userAgentString ="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-ch; HTC Sensation Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"; 
UserAgent agent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgentString);




        Browser browser = agent.getBrowser();       
        System.out.println("Browser Type :"+browser.getBrowserType());
        System.out.println("Browser Name :"+browser.getName());

        Version version = agent.getBrowserVersion();
        System.out.println("Browser Version :"+version.getVersion());


        OperatingSystem os = agent.getOperatingSystem();
        System.out.println("OS Name  :"+os.getName());  
        System.out.println("DEVICE TYPE : "+ os.getDeviceType());
        System.out.println("OS Manufacturer :"+os.getManufacturer());
```

or anyother Java Api to find out all the value(Device Name,Device Type ,Browser Type,Browser Version,OS Name OS version)using USER AGENT String?